# How do I get substitute() function to work on individual lines like s///g

Tags: regular-expression

When I select a range visually and run this command:

`:'<,'>s/\(.*\)\s\+#.*$/\1/g`

It removes the text at the end of **each line** that starts with `#` which is what I want.

I want to run a vim function that does the same on the text in a register to clean it up the text:

```
function! PasteTasksClean()
    let tasks = getreg('+')
    let clean_tasks = substitute(tasks, '\(.*\)\s\+#.*$', '\1', 'g')
    call setreg('+', clean_tasks)
    :put +
endfunction
```

However, substitute acts on the entire string, not on each line, and so only the last line has the unwanted text removed. I didn't see any modifier flags that would let me accomplish this.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Note also that you can simplify your regexp, there's no need to use a capture group and replace with itself in this case. The `$` after a greedy `.*` can be omitted too. You also don't need the `/g` since you're matching only once per line. `:'<,'>s/\s\+#.*//` does the same. EDIT: I actually missed that the intent was to capture only from the *last* occurrence of `#` in the line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function in Vimscript always considers the input as a single line, even if it has embedded newlines. It's different from the `:substitute` Ex command in that sense, mainly because these two are typically used in different contexts.

One way to work around this is to change your regular expression to work in the new context. Which is often, but not always possible.

Another way around is to split your input into lines, then apply a `substitute()` on each of them and finally join them back together. Using this approach, you can use the same regexp as you use in `:s` in virtually all cases. You can use `split()`, `map()` and `join()` to work out the list operations needed here.

In your example:

```
function! PasteTasksClean()
    let tasks = split(getreg('+'), "\n")
    let clean_tasks = map(tasks, {_, m -> substitute(m, '\(.*\)\s\+#.*$', '\1', 'g')})
    call setreg('+', join(clean_tasks, "\n"))
    :put +
endfunction
```

See `:help split()`, `:help map()`, `:help join()` for more details, also `:help lambda` for the `{_, m -> ...}` function syntax.

Comment: You can also simplify that to `let clean_tasks = map(tasks, {_, m -> substitute(m, '\s\+#.*', '', '')})` using the same simplification I described in a comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I thought about splitting the lines up into an array an iterating over them separately. Seemed too painful. What I ended up doing is rewriting the regex to be more explicit about what characters will follow the last `#` sign in the line and replacing it with a newline: `substitute('\s\+#[0-9a-f]\{8\}[ \t]*\n', '\n', 'g')`. Not very pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @StevieD Ah yes good point! There's also `\s\+#[^#]*$`, or `\s\+#.\{-}$` (using the non-greedy `\{-}` which finds the shortest string, or `.*\zs\s\+#.*` which uses `\zs` to mark the start of the match... Also, it seems yours will only take a single `\s` out, since the preceding `.*` will greedily take all others first...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your matching pattern a little to handle multiple lines:

- you’re not matching anything anymore, but any non-newline characters, so `.` becomes `[^\n]`
- you’re not matching until “the end” any more, but also until the next newline
- Also your capture group contains no information (`.*` goes not restrain what lines your pattern matches on or anything like that) so I’ve removed it.

This should work:

```
let clean_tasks = substitute(tasks, '\s\+#[^\n]*\(\n\|$\)', '\1', 'g')
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried matching against everything except newline character at one point. Couldn't seem to get it to work. I think the problem with your regex is it would wipe out everything from the very first `#` sign going forward. I want to keep everything up until the last `#` sign.

Comment: You should give it a try @StevieD, it works as intented. I’ve tested it.